# Random factor design structure for diversity surveys with repeat visits

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, diversity

I’m involved in a project where we surveyed native insect communities across a large spatial gradient. Each site was surveyed twice over two summers for a total of 4 visits. We are hoping to analyze patterns in the abundance and richness of these communities across different land use types, regions, and management regimes. We are currently using both `glmmPQL` and `lmer` depending on the distribution of each variable and are struggling to build an effective structure for our random effects.

Our data is currently structured such that each visit to a site is its own row, such that each site is listed multiple times.

We have two questions regarding how to structure our random effects.

First, do we need to include both SITE and VISIT as a random effect to address the repeated measures, or is it sufficient to just include SITE?

Secondly, if we have 1 predictor variable that was measured only once per year and another that was measured twice per year, how would this change our random effect structure?

Comment: I've added word "design" to the title in order not to confuse with "factor structure" of a factor analysis

Answer (score 1):

1. Site must be included. Including visit makes only sense if all observations with the same visit index were measured roughly under same conditions / at the same time. Just because they were both labeled with '1' doesn't make them a group. Seems unlikely for a typical field campaign.
2. This is a bit vague, but assuming you have site as RE and two independent models with different predictors, there seems no need to change the RE structure.

Comment: Thank you @Florian Hartig, this makes sense, I am going to remove visit from my model